# JQuery - what does this mean $('#name=grund')?

Tags: jquery, html

I have seen this jQuery-line:

```
$('#name=grund')
```

what does this mean? I can see, that there is a element with the ID "grund".. does this mean, that there should be a element (input) with a name-attrubute?

Comment: That means an element with the `id` of `name=grund`. In HTML5 the `=` character is valid in `id` attributes. Whether this is the intended behaviour for this selector is another matter. Selecting by attribute would seem more appropriate in this context, but the selector would then need to be `$('[name=grund]')`

Comment: means you have a id named name=grund  :))

Comment: = is not a dom/jquery selector, is part of the id

Comment: 1) thanks guys!!! :)  ..  2) oh shit, really? why would someone do something like that??? -.-

Comment: @crunchy some string manipulation , ids must be unique ,someone need the value after = , multiple motives

Comment: It should be noted that this selector, in its current state, will not work. The equal sign still has to be escaped with two backslashes ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfjkx5uq/)).

Comment: @madalin ivascu .. aaaahh... okay :) .. that sounds logic :) .. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

This is called the #id Selector

Here you can find all selectors
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: Please don't use W3S as a reference; their information is often outdated and/or wrong. The jQuery documentation is always accurate and up to date: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ (downvotes not mine by the way)

Comment: Thomas Rohde did not deserve 2 downvotes, as he is spot on with his answer despite the source. It's just an ID selector.